# How to use regular expression to match in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have some text on an HTML page and I want to use a regular expression to match but I'm having a hard time.

```
<tr id="part1AModel.errors">
             <td colspan="5">  
                <h3><font color="red">Validation Error</font></h3>You must correct the following error(s) before proceeding:
                <ul>

                        <li><font color="red">The requested effective date entered is not an expedited date. If an expedite is required, please either leave the default effective date or change the effective date to a date that is less than 31 days. If the effective date entered is the date you want, please be sure to select "No"Â for Requested Expedite Treatment and uncheck the Earliest Effective Date checkbox.<br/></font> </li>

                </ul>  
                For assistance, please contact the Help Desk.<hr> 
             </td></tr>
```

the above is my code and i want to try to match against the

```
<tr id="part1AModel.errors"> </tr>
```

so if it exists I get it returned but I can't figure out the syntax for the life of it. I used

```
/<tr id=\"part1AModel.errors\">(.*?)<\/tr>/
```

but it does not match. What am I missing here?

Comment: I think there's something you need to do if you want to match across line-breaks.. you should also be escaping the dot in the id= part.

Comment: Consider using XML parsing extensions such as DOM or XMLReader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the `.` dot pattern matches any character except the newline. To have `.` also match the newline character, use the `/s` `PCRE_DOTALL` option. This is mentioned in the PHP regexp reference for the dot pattern:

http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.dot.php

> Outside a character class, a dot in the pattern matches any one character in the subject, including a non-printing character, but not (by default) newline. If the PCRE_DOTALL option is set, then dots match newlines as well.

You can apply this to your example as follows which I've verified:

`/<tr id=\"part1AModel\.errors\">(.*?)<\/tr>/s`

I also made the following changes:

- escaped the `.` period to match a literal period instead of any character.
- moved the `?` after the `()` capture group to make the capture optional like so:

`/<tr id=\"part1AModel\.errors\">([\s\S]*)?<\/tr>/`

Using this with `preg_match` will return:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => <tr id="part1AModel.errors">
         <td colspan="5">  
            <h3><font color="red">Validation Error</font></h3>You must correct the following error(s) before proceeding:
            <ul>

                    <li><font color="red">The requested effective date entered is not an expedited date. If an expedite is required, please either leave the default effective date or change the effective date to a date that is less than 31 days. If the effective date entered is the date you want, please be sure to select "No"Â for Requested Expedite Treatment and uncheck the Earliest Effective Date checkbox.<br/></font> </li>

            </ul>  
            For assistance, please contact the Help Desk.<hr> 
         </td></tr>
        [1] => 0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
         <td colspan="5">  
            <h3><font color="red">Validation Error</font></h3>You must correct the following error(s) before proceeding:
            <ul>

                    <li><font color="red">The requested effective date entered is not an expedited date. If an expedite is required, please either leave the default effective date or change the effective date to a date that is less than 31 days. If the effective date entered is the date you want, please be sure to select "No"Â for Requested Expedite Treatment and uncheck the Earliest Effective Date checkbox.<br/></font> </li>

            </ul>  
            For assistance, please contact the Help Desk.<hr> 
         </td>
        [1] => 28
    )
)
```

Comment: `s (PCRE_DOTALL)`
_If this modifier is set, a dot metacharacter in the pattern matches all characters, including newlines. Without it, newlines are excluded. This modifier is equivalent to Perl's /s modifier. A negative class such as [^a] always matches a newline character, independent of the setting of this modifier._ http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Comment: Thanks @linden2015. Great info on both PHP and Perl. I've updated the answer to reflect this with a reference to PHP regexp  dot pattern.